# Error Time Limit exceeded Add digits of number

Tags: python

I have used iterative approach to add all digits of a number till the sum is a unit number. My code is:

```
    def addDigits(self, num):
    self.x=num
    a=[]
    sum=0
    count=0
    count1=0
    p=0
    while((self.x)/10>0):
        while(self.x>0):
            self.x=self.x/10
            count=count+1
        self.x=num
        while(count>0):
            if(count==1):
                self.x=self.x%10
                sum=sum+self.x
            else:
                self.x=self.x/(10**(count-1))
                sum=sum+self.x    
                self.x=num
                self.x=self.x%(10**(count-1))


            count=count-1

        self.x=sum 

        num=self.x
    return self.x
```

I am getting time exceeded error for input where sum>10.Please suggest some ways to solve this problem so that correct output can be there

Comment: Sorry got it forgot to add sum=0 at end

Comment: use http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Taking just this statement to keep it simple self.x=self.x/10, self.x will never be equal to or less than zero (assuming you are using Python 3x), it will just be very, very small, so you have an infinite loop.  I would suggest that you add a counter to the loop, print self.x and the counter, and exit the loop after the counter reaches some reasonable number, like 100 to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the algorithm: here are 2 implementations (with 1 respectively 2 nested loops):

```
def addDigits(self, num):
    aux = num
    sum = 0
    while aux > 9:
        sum = sum + aux % 10
        aux = aux / 10
        if aux <= 9:
            sum = sum + aux
            aux = sum
            sum = 0
    return aux

def addDigits(self, num):
    aux = num
    sum = 0
    while True:
        while aux > 9:
            sum = sum + aux % 10
            aux = aux / 10
        sum = sum + aux
        aux = sum
        sum = 0
        if aux <= 9:
            break
    return aux
```

**Notes**:

- I replaced `self.x` with `aux`; there's no reason to have a private member used just for storing a method internal (and temporary) data
- Since the method does not depend of any class members it can be decorated as `@classmethod`

Comment: Hi, did you find your answer here?